# Upload image to dropbox and get back share link in one shot?

Tags: dropbox-api

I am in situation where I have to keep the XHR calls to a minimum. My users of want to upload a file and get back a share link to it. My challenge is I need to do this with a single XHR call.

I currently add the file like this:

```
        xhr('https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/Screenshot.png?overwrite=false', {
            aMethod: 'PUT',
            Headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + gEditor.dropboxOauth.access_token,
                'Content-Type': myBlob.type,
                'Content-Length': myBlob.size
            },
            aPostData: myBlob,
            aResponseType: 'json'
        });
```

Then with the resultant response object I get a share link with this call:

```
        xhr('https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/media/auto' + uploadedJson.path, {
            aMethod: 'POST',
            Headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + gEditor.dropboxOauth.access_token
            },
            aPostData: {
                locale: 'en-US'
            },
            aResponseType: 'json'
        });
```

Is there anyway to do this with a single call?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible with the Dropbox API to get a link to a file in the same API call as uploading it, but we'll consider this a feature request.

Comment: Thanks Greg, i htink you're a dropbox official guy may i chat with you please for a second it was about perm link to the file, right now im doing the trick here: attaching ?raw=1 to the file. I'm making a firefox addon so privacy is a concern so google drive is something we refuse to use. Will the `?raw=1` on non short shared url trick ensure permeantent link i can place in `<img src="">`? Also is it possible to delete a file by id? sorry about this i got excited an official guy responded :P i opened stack chat in case you are available i would love to chat what im making:

Comment: Promise just 5min chat, because in my addon i keep logs of screenshot and a link to the "delete url" but if hte user renames the file on their dropbox, then my delete url wont work as i currently pass the file name on creation. :( is it possible to delete it based on any file that has `rev` of blah or something? this is my addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/

Comment: In the interest of making the information neatly available to others, can you post new nicely formatted questions for these questions like you did with this one above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for saying this one was neat :) I'll definitely do that thanks very very much Greg! I was always a dropbox and box fan as they are the originals :) Awesome staff makes it sooo much cooler :)